# se puede subir a Vercel "gratis", un proyecto de un back (nodejs express y javascript) , un front (con javascript, react y tailwind) y bd mongodb?

Tags: vercel, back

mi proyecto es un proyecto de una inmobiliaria que tiene un back, front y una base de datos mongodb. Generalmente veo en los videos que siempre suben o el back o el front a vercel gratis, pero no vi como subir la aplicacion completa, es decir back, front y base de datos.

Comment: Hasta el momento no he utilizado `Vercel`, lo que sí te puedo decir y asegurar es que los programadores que leen la documentación oficial de la tecnología que quieren aprender, avanzan más rápido que los que la ignoran. Eres nuevo en el sitio, aquí la temática es especial: problema específico -> respuesta específica (y algunas raras excepciones), para que puedas formular preguntas con buenas chances de obtener respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 PD: dentro del mismo Vercel encontré esto: https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.